# How to preserve $ in shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I would like to preserve $0 in the following script after executing.

```
cat << EOF > script.awk
BEGIN {
if ($0 != 99) {
    count[idx]++;
    sum[idx] += $0;
      }} END
EOF
```

After executing this it is writing my first file instead of writing $0.
i.e.

```
BEGIN {
if (file1 != 99) {
    count[idx]++;
    sum[idx] += file1;
      }} END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape `$0` as `\$0` to solve the problem.